# Rename "Pipelines" to "Builds" in ADO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I customize the "Pipeline" tab in Azure Devps (Image 1) so that it is renamed to "Builds" (Image 2)?

[image: Pipelines]

[image: Builds]

Comment: You don't. The feature was renamed. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rename “Pipelines” to “Builds” in ADO

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and is not an issue. There is no way to fix it at present.

Azure devops team working on an updated user experience to manage our pipelines. These updates make the pipelines experience modern and consistent with the direction of Azure DevOps.

Moreover, these updates **bring together classic build pipelines and multi-stage YAML pipelines into a single experience**. It is mobile-friendly and brings various improvements to how you manage your pipelines.

You could check the document [Azure DevOps Pipelines – Multi-Stage Pipelines and YAML for Continuous Delivery](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-pipelines-multi-stage-pipelines-and-yaml-for-continuous-delivery/) for some more details.

Since Multi-Stage Pipelines and YAML for Continuous Delivery introduced, Builds are no longer just a single build as before, but also include the CD part. At this time, Builds are no longer suitable as tabs, so they are changed to Pipelines.

This is a modification of product update progress.